# Rooks covering Dark Squares on a Chessboard

Tags: mathematics, optimization, chess, checkerboard

How many rooks are required such that all dark squares on the chessboard are covered by at least one rook.

Comment: If I now have the answer, should I post it?

Comment: I suppose you want the minimal number of rooks?

Comment: How many rooks are **required**, so yes.

Comment: @SnySmartie I laughed so hard at the edit history. Keep it up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Here is a configuration with 4 rooks.
>  [image]

> As  justhalf and JaapScherphuis have pointed out, this can easily proven to be optimal: each rook can only cover two of the squares of the black diagonal. So 4 rooks are necessary to cover all the black squares.

Comment: The proof is easy. Each rook can cover at most 8 black squares, and 32 need to be covered.

Comment: Or, look at the 8 diagonal black squares. One rook can only cover 2.

Comment: The proof of @JaapScherphuis also implies that none of the rooks can be placed on a black square.

Comment: thanks again for you comments, included the proof of optimality in the post.